# optimizing string search for a single byte

Tags: c++, string-search

In general, string search algorithms (like Boyer-Moore) are optimized for cases where the *search string* is long-ish.  That is, Boyer-Moore is great because by lining up the search string with our text, we can skip `N = len(search string)` characters if the end of the search string doesn't match the text.

But what if our search string is really short?  Like a single byte or character?  In this case, Boyer-Moore doesn't help much.

So, what are some alternative algorithms for speeding up searching?

I know that many optimized library search routines (like `memchr` in C), take the strategy of reading the input string word by word, rather than char by char.  So on a 64-bit machine, 8 bytes can be examined at once, rather than a single byte.

I'd like to know how these optimized string/byte searches actually work.  How does the actual comparison work then?  I know it obviously must involve bit masking - but I don't see how performing all the bit masking is any better than simply search character by character.

So, suppose our search char is `0xFF`.  Ignoring alignment issues, let's say we have some input buffer: `void* buf`.  We can read it word by word by saying:

```
const unsigned char search_char = 0xFF;
unsigned char* bufptr = static_cast<unsigned char*>(buf);
unsigned char* bufend = bufptr + BUF_SIZE;

while (bufptr != bufend)
{
   // Ignore alignment concerns for now, assume BUF_SIZE % sizeof(uintptr_t) == 0
   //
   std::uinptr_t next_word = *reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t*>(bufptr);

   // ... but how do we compare next_word with our search char?

   bufptr += sizeof(std::uintptr_t);
}
```

I also realize that the above code is not strictly portable, because `std::uintptr_t` isn't guaranteed to actually be word size.  But let's assume for the sake of this question that `std::uinptr_t` is equal to the processor word size.  (An actual implementation would likely need platform-specific macros to get the actual word-size)

So, how do we actually check if the byte `0xFF` occurs anywhere in the value of `next_word`?

We can use `OR` operations of course, but it seems we'd still need to perform a lot of OR'ing and bit shifting to check each byte of `next_word`, at which point it becomes questionable whether this optimization is actually any better than simply scanning character by character.

Comment: In order to speed up a search, you will need to change the data structure, such as sorting it or using a linked list or hash generator.  Sometimes, with small data, a brute force linear search is your fastest alternative.  Some processors have specialized functions for searching for a byte in memory.

Comment: If the data to be searched is huge, you may want to consider using multiple threads for searching.  One thorn with this technique is the overhead in setting up the threads.  Ideally, you could delegate thread processing to cores, such as cores in the GPU or processor.

Comment: Possibly see [this page](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html##ValueInWord)

Comment: I'm aware of all the issues with speeding up search - for huge data sets something like a suffix trie might be useful.  I'm just specifically asking about optimized single-char searches that make use of reading a word at a time.  I'd just like to understand how the actual comparisons are done - what sort of bitwise logic is done to speed up the search?

Comment: @Hasturkun - thanks that's exactly what I was looking for.  If you post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this snippet from Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html##ValueInWord):

```
#define haszero(v) (((v) - 0x01010101UL) & ~(v) & 0x80808080UL)
#define hasvalue(x,n) \
(haszero((x) ^ (~0UL/255 * (n))))
```

It effectively XORs each byte with the character to be tested, then determines if any byte is now zero.

At this point you can get the location of the matching byte (or bytes) from the return value of the expression, e.g. the value will be 0x00000080 if the least significant byte matches the value.